# Порты, необходимые для FTP

Tags: ftp, порты

Есть FTPS сервер за файрволлом. Какие порты надо открыть для входящего и исходящего трафика?

Answer (score 1):

Для самого протокола нужно 20/TCP и 21/TCP (см. [список стандартных портов](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%EF%E8%F1%EE%EA_%EF%EE%F0%F2%EE%E2_TCP_%E8_UDP)).

И если у вас сервер будет работать в пассивном режиме, то нужно открыть еще пару любых портов и указать их в конфиге ftp в разделе о пассивном режиме.